# jQuery - call function when animate

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate

Is it possible to call some function in `.animate` event? I have to call `resize()` function for every resize event on some div.

For an example, I call function on window resize event:

```
$(window).resize(resize);
```

But now I wish to call this function inside animate event(every changed pixel(like `.resize` does)).

```
selector['el']['box'].animate({width:selector['el']['box'].width() - 250}, 500);
selector['el']['box'].promise().done(function() {resize();});
```

But this is not what I want, because I wish resize function to be called all the time, not only on the end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use its step function, like:

```
selector['el']['box'].animate({width:selector['el']['box'].width() - 250}, 500,
step: function( currentStep ){       
    //step animation complete
   //do something here
});
```

See :: **step** in [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Yes, this function will be called when animation will end. I need function to be called during animate, not at the end :)

Comment: @klemzy you could use "step" function, do you mean something like that..!

Answer (score 2):

step function is ur solution
here is what jquery documentation says

> step
>
> Type: Function( Number now, Tween tween )
> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated element. This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween object to change the value of the property before it is set.

See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xHXGB/1/)**
you will see width properties changing step wise

```
$( "div").css({
    position: "fixed",
    left: "50px"
})
.animate(
{
    width: 1000
},
{
    duration: 500,
    step: function( currentLeft, animProperties ){
        $( "span" ).html( $( "span" ).html()+"<br>value:"+currentLeft+" state:"+animProperties);
        console.log( "Left: ", currentLeft );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  selector['el']['box'].animate({
          // for example 
          opacity: 0.25,
          left: '+=50',
          height: 'toggle'
        },
        {
        duration: 500,
        step: function() {
          //add your code here
        });
```

Add your code to second function block.