# jQuery animation, fire a function every other second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make an upload script with jQuery and a loading bar aswell.

I got a field with multiple upload possibility. Every file gets two second on the loading bar.

So to count the time i have this:

```
var length = array.length; 
var time = length*2; 
var totalTime = time*1000; // To count the totaltime, not milliseconds.
```

My question now is, if i upload several files, we say like 3 files. 
Then i have 6 seconds in the loading bar, is there a way to make a function fire every two seconds? 
Do i have to do this outside the animation with setinterval? 
If so how do i stop a setinterval? 
Or is it possible to do it inside the animation?

```js
$(".filesUpload").on("change", function() {
  var files = $(".filesUpload").prop("files");
  var names = $.map(files, function(val) {
    return val.name;
  });
  totalFiles = names.length;
  $("#uploadBar").modal('show');

});
$("#uploadBar").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  var time = totalFiles * 2;
  var totalTime = time * 1000; // Get seconds, not milliseconds.
  $(".progress-bar-success").animate({
    width: "+=100%"
  }, totalTime);
});
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="uploadBar">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="filesUpload[]" class="filesUpload" multiple="">
</form>
```

Comment: Is this done with ajax?  Can you show the code that takes the selected items, submits them, and triggers the animation?

Comment: I dont have this code yet, i did it yesterday, but forgot about the animation plugin so i deleted it and should started over. But i can remake this function in just some mins. I can post a fiddle when im done!

Comment: If you decide to use `setinterval()` then you'll want to set it to a global variable such as: `var t = setInterval(function() {...}, time);`. You can then stop this with `clearInterval(t);`.

Comment: @zero298 Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4rwdjjL/

Comment: Are you trying to have three separate bar animations?

Comment: No only one bar animation.

Comment: Okay i see what you want

Comment: I think you are looking for the step method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646470/jquery-call-function-when-animate

Comment: @Ray if i use the step function, then i have to count how many vars in the array, and count that length split with 100 (because the full width is 100%) and then run it after right percent. And then i have a followup question, how to do that count without 300 ifs?

Comment: I may have a solution, with interval, if i start the interval when the animation starts, and stops the interval when the animation stops, can this be a solution?

Comment: Try doing something like this: divide percentage by files. Loop over the animate that will do a specific % equal to the divide, execute callback after animate to execute function. In this case, three animated equal to 33.33 and 3 function calls